# Regex from stringified-array

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How do you extract regex values from a stringified-array?

Sample data:

```
with data as (select 1 as id, '["abc_def_123","uvw_xyz_456"]'::string as my_field)
select * from data
```

`my_field` could have up to 4 items (if important).

Desired output:

```
--------------------------------
|  id  |  f1   |  f2   |  f3   |
--------------------------------
|  1   |  abc  |  def  |  123  |
|  1   |  uvw  |  xyz  |  456  |
--------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
with data as (
    select 1 as id, '["abc_def_123","uvw_xyz_456"]'::string as my_field
),
json_data as (
    select id, parse_json(my_field) as json from data
),
flattened_data as (
    SELECT id, split(f.value::string, '_') as splitted_c
    FROM json_data,
    lateral flatten(input => json_data.json) f   
)
SELECT 
    id, 
    splitted_c[0]::string as f1, 
    splitted_c[1]::string as f2, 
    splitted_c[2]::string as f3
from flattened_data;
```

Result:

```
+----+-----+-----+-----+
| ID | F1  | F2  | F3  |
|----+-----+-----+-----|
|  1 | abc | def | 123 |
|  1 | uvw | xyz | 456 |
+----+-----+-----+-----+
```